# TypeScript complaining on a property that does not exist, while it does exist on the interface

Tags: typescript

having this odd issue which sure seems like a bug in TS.
getting an error of

`Error:(221, 76) TS2339:Property 'item' does not exist on type 'ISimpleListItem | { [key: string]: ISimpleListItem; }'.`

but as you can see from my image, my interface clearly has `item` in its definition.

so the error comes from me doing

`var itemSelected: AdnetTargetModel = this.simpleList.getSelected().item;`

and interface is in image below:

[image]

and this is the method that returns the type:

`public getSelected(): ISimpleListItem | { [key: string]: ISimpleListItem } {
        if (this.multiSelect)
            return this.m_metadata;
        for (let v in this.m_metadata) {
            if (this.m_metadata[v].selected == true)
                return this.m_metadata[v];
        }
    }`

the only way to fix it is to force TS to recognize the proper type by doing

`var itemSelected: AdnetTargetModel = (this.simpleList.getSelected() as ISimpleListItem).item;`

strang :/

regards

Sean

Comment: As the error says, `this.simpleList.getSelected()`is not of type ISimpleListItem. It's of type `ISimpleListItem | { [key: string]: ISimpleListItem`. So it can't guarantee thet there is a property item. The value could be a `{ [key: string]: ISimpleListItem`. Just like, if the type was `string | number`, accessing its length attribute isn't safe: TS can't know if it's a string or a number.